# Construction of a pushout square

Tags: category-theory

The question is stated at follows:

> Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]\times [0,1]$ be the function defined by $f(x)=(x,0)$ and let $*$ denote a singleton set. Prove that the pushout of the corner
>
> $[0,1]\xrightarrow{~~~~f~~~~} [0,1]\times [0,1]\\$
>
> $~~~\Bigg\downarrow~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\\$
>
> $~~*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$
>
> is a triangle.

I tried to construct the object $P$ on the bottom right with different objects like $([0,1]\times [0,1],*)$ or just $(*,0)$, but I don't think I can define the morphism very well: the first choice makes the map from $*$ to $P$ be dependent on the initial choice $x\in [0,1]$ and I don't see how the second choice would make the morphism from $P$ to any other object $T$ unique. I am also not sure what the "triangle" is referring to: would that just be the triangle on the bottom right? Thank you!

Comment: Hint: construct the pushout as a quotient of the union of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ and $*$

Comment: What category?...

Comment: @Randall It doesn't say... which is why I'm confused

Comment: It holds for the category of sets, but also for the category of topological spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[0,1] \times [0,1]$ is a filled square, and the map $f : [0,1] \to [0,1] \times [0,1]$ is the inclusion of the bottom side $[0,1] \times \{0\}$. Hence, the pushout with the unique map $[0,1] \to \star$ collapses this side to a point. The result is clearly a triangle.

To make this a bit more formal, let $T \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be the filled triangle with the points $(0,1)$, $(1,1)$ and $(\frac{1}{2},0)$. Define a map $\phi : [0,1] \times [0,1] \to T$ by "squeezing" the square on the bottom:
$$\phi(x,y) = (y \cdot x+(1-y) \cdot \tfrac{1}{2} ,y)$$
Notice that $y \cdot x+(1-y) \cdot \tfrac{1}{2}$ interpolates between the "original" coordinate $x$ and the "target" coordinate $\frac{1}{2}$. We have $\phi(x,0)=(\frac{1}{2},0)$, so that $\phi$ is constant on the bottom side. Now your task is to show that $\phi$ is universal with this property.

Comment: Thank you! I'm afraid I'm not really familiar with the terminologies: would you mind explaining a bit about what a filled triangle/square is? I'm not sure if I understand every correctly, but why would we need to include (0,1) and (1,1) in T if we are not using them?

Comment: Please draw a picture! I use terms from elementary geometry which you learned in school.

Comment: Ohhh sorry, I thought it was some terminology in the categorical diagram